# LESS passing arguments into mixins

Tags: less

I am a little new to LESS, so I am trying to grasp how to pass an argument into a mixin for example i have:

```
@delay: 6s;
.animation-delay (@delay) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: @delay;
    -moz-animation-delay: @delay;
    -o-animation-delay: @delay;
    -ms-animation-delay: @delay;
    animation-delay: @delay; 
}
```

and later on my stylesheet i want to do something like this:

```
.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(/static/template/slides/slide-2.jpg)
    .animation-delay(@delay);   
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(/static/template/slides/slide-3.jpg);
    .animation-delay (@delay + 6); 
}
```

As I am getting errors from less.js I assume i am not doing this right!

Comment: _What does the error say?_

Comment: ParseError: Unrecognised input
in slideshow.less on line 48, column 2:

47 background-image: url(/static/template/slides/slide-2.jpg)
48 .animation-delay(@delay); 
49}

Comment: seems to be working now, must have been something cached

Comment: @DestinationDesigns: I get the same error that you have mentioned in comments and it is because of a missing semi-colon after `background-image` declaration for `:nth-child(2)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Less is a dynamic style sheet language that can be compiled into Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) and run on the client-side or server-side. In other words it is a CSS preprocessor which compiles javascript code into CSS rules.

> Every `CSS` code is a valid `LESS` code, but not vice versa.

You cannot expect that CSS will recognize `@delay` variable and its value. Everything you want to do with CSS rules, you do it inside `.less` file.